# You have specified a database that is not empty, please specify an empty database

Tags: postgresql, jira, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to connect to an RDS cluster in AWS that's an Aurora PostgreSQL database. It's a brand-new database that I created along with the instances that I have Jira deployed to. However, when I try to connect to the instance from the Jira configuration screen I get this error

```
You have specified a database that is not empty, please specify an empty database.
```

I haven't touched this database at all, why is it giving me this error? I have one read and one write database in my cluster and the "hostname" is the endpoint for my write database, which is what the docs say. Could this be an issue with the Jira version I'm using?

This is the download link I'm using in my user-data script to install Jira. I'm also using PostgreSQL version 12.11

```
https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/downloads/binary/atlassian-servicedesk-4.19.1-x64.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to a different PostgreSQL version and now it's working.

PostgreSQL version 12.11 was giving me the error and switching to version 13.7 works as expected.